# Wordpress plugin insert query is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, insert, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm calling a wordpress plugin function via a front end page which is working good, the function that i m calling is inserting data into the database but its not working
here is the query i m running(which is not working):

The function is  being called on submit as echo value is printed but no data is being inserted

```
function savedata(){
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit;
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('questoptions',
     array(
        'question_id' => $_POST['question_id'],
        'text' => $_POST['text']

),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%s'
    )
);

die();
return true;
}
```

here is the function calling this function from front end:

```
function abc(){
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: { action: 'savedata', 'question_id': document.getElementById('question_id').value, 'text': document.getElementById('text').value },               
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

anyone has any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add full code for ajax functions which you have created with filter without this never call savedata

Comment: @ravipatel this is the whole code for ajax

Comment: wp_ajax_, wp_ajax_nopriv_ Not found this functions  code.

Comment: because there is no function like that

Comment: should i add it ??

Comment: yes, Please check my answer code & given us a replay if you have any issue.

Comment: $wpdb->insert('') stored in variable based on success return a value for check Ajax response.

Comment: Now check again my code, whats word now  display after submit a data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wordpress ajax function infromation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)
Add this functions and check your post data is called or not ?

> wp_ajax_nopriv_(action) executes for users that are not logged in.

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_savedata', 'custom_savedata' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_savedata', 'custom_savedata' );

    function custom_savedata() {
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['question_id'])):
        $data = ($wpdb->insert('table_name_add_here', array(
                    'question_id'        => $_POST['question_id'],
                    'text' => $_POST['text'],
                )
        ));
        if($data){
            echo 'success';
        }else{
            echo 'not success';
        }
    else:
        echo 'please check post data';
    endif;  

    exit;
}
```

Comment: its printing the array

Comment: Good, Now you can execute your code. Without this ajax function wp not called your function. Injoy

Comment: i dont understand what you wanna say
in my function this part was doing good it was printing the data the problem is in the query ,,, which is not inserting the data into the database

Answer (score -1):

plz remove second line

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit;'
```

so it execute rest of code and return.

if u should try this and also not get solution than u must be check your database table name if table name pretend by 'wp' than u should try wp_ questoptions as table name in query instead of questoptions.

thinks. might be it will help you.

Comment: enable database error display via $wpdb->show_errors()
check what query is being formed and run via $wpdb->last_query

Comment: this is ajax call so u must be use wp_ajax.

Comment: check question_id datatype it should not be int.

Comment: must be available this two line in function.php 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_savedata', 'savedata');
add_action('wp_ajax_savedata', 'savedata');

Comment: these are added alreday as i said the function is being called the problem is in the insert query inside the function